# How to give sitename in different languages!!!! in spree rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I would like to know how to give different sitename for different languages.
When I tried to change spree.rb

```
 Spree.config do |config|
     Example:
     Uncomment to override the default site name.
    if I18n.locale == :ar
    config.site_name = "الأربعاء"
    else
    config.site_name = "Spree Demo Site"
    end

end
```

It gives an error on console
invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) (SyntaxError)
invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
syntax error, unexpected $end, expe
cting keyword_end
config.site_name = "الأربعاء"

and admin interface has only one sitename facility

And if i give sitename replacement in ar.yml file it doesn't change with change in language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did and got success

```
<% if I18n.locale == :ar %>
<title> تجريبي |<%= title %></title>
 <html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
<% else %>
<title>demo |<%= title %> </title>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the `i18n` gem and to define your translations in `app/config/locales/ar.yml` file , similar to this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/138-i18n-revised?view=asciicast).